# Python memory leak which is not recognized by profiler

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, guppy

The program can work fine for days, but at some random point it starts growing ~60MB/hour.

1. Profilers like guppy and pympler doesn't show leaked memory. (they show ~30mb used, while ps resident memory use is 1,5GB)
2. Gdb-heap C profiler shows a lot of chunks of memory as 'uncategorized'.
3. Gc.collect didn't show garbage collection problems.
4. We don't use any non-default C libraries, so I don't think it's C level leak.

Is that a dead end? Can something else be done to find the issue?

Comment: Add a thread/process which is continuously tracking memory usage and when the pattern is detected generate a process interrupt exception -- hopefully the traceback will give a clue what was executing at the moment. This will be hit and miss, mostly miss, but better than doing nothing.

Comment: P.S. You can automatically restart your process after the forced stop, so this will not only monitor, but also "make the problem go away" for the time being

Comment: P.P.S. Use OS to impose a limit on how much memory can be consumed by the process. You can also pull some physical memory out. Limit virtual memory as well -- force it to generate "Out of memory" exception -- if you succeed then the exception traceback will pinpoint the problem.